# Comparing general search engine and a meta search engine. Paired t test or independent t-test?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, model-comparison

I have built a domain-specific search engine, a meta-search engine. This search engine, of course, take its results from other search engines like Google, Bing, Yahoo and stuff. Then does some classification to filter the results.
Now, I'm doing an evaluation on the precision of search results returned by this search engine towards the precision of search results returned from a general search engine.

So I queried a number of queries to my search engine, count the precision of each result returned, and compute the average of the precisions.
I do the same queries to a general search engine, which in this case is Google. And by so compute the average of the precisions.

I use t-test two see if the difference between these precisions statistically significantly differ. What I can't understand now, is it paired t-test or independent one?

I heard from my professor that it should be independent t-test, since the sample sets come from two different search engines. But in my mind, since the sample (search results returned) are displayed based on same queries in order, and meta-search engine takes its results from several general search engines, it should be paired t-test. On the other hand I know it as well, that paired t-test should be done on SAME sample, different treatments.

Which do I choose? Need help.
I enclose the screen shoot of the search results as well, to make my question more clear and understandable. Thanks. [image: How it looks like]

Comment: Your samples are the different queries and your different treatments are the two search engines (both treatments are applied to each query). Clearly you have to use a paired t test!

Comment: clearly paired on 'query'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, the results from Google and My Search are not independent (since you have the "query" factor). Consider a simpler example: instead of calculating "precision", take the number of hits. Don't you think that these numbers will be very well correlated between the two search engines? After all, a query like "dog" will return many more hits than "multilinearity" in *both* engines.

Try to look at this from this point of view: instead of calculating the precision of the two machines, for each query you calculate the *difference* in precision. Instead of having two columns, your statistic is now a single variable and the hypothesis that you wish to check is whether this variable is significantly different from 0.

This is *exactly* a situation to use a paired test.

Comment: Now I'm getting confused, my professor said that I'm using different sets of data (the search results), despite of the query. If I insisted to use paired t-test (just like how I considered it), I'm afraid my professor wouldn't defend me on my mini-thesis examination date. Sounds cheesy I know. Any more advice?

Comment: Plot the number of hits from "My Search" vs. number of hits for Google and ask your professor why the results are correlated (and I would be surprised if they didn't) if they are independent. Look up the definition of probabilistic independence; if two random variables are independence, their covariance (and, what follows, their correlation) should be zero as well.

Comment: OK then, thank you.. I already got through the examination, and still I ended up using independence. -_- But thanks for your answer..